# jQuery UI Dialog - Height always incorrect on first show, and vertical centering incorrect when page is scrolled

Tags: height, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using a jQuery UI Dialog to show a simple loader when the user presses a certain button (to prevent the user interacting with the page). The button fires an AJAX request which updates a certain part of the website (I.e. the footer).

## Problem 1 - Incorrect height on first show

My first problem is that the first time the Dialog is displayed it's height is 51px, not 94px as declared. In fact I've discovered that it's always 43px less on first display, no matter what I set the height to, and despite the fact that I have the `minHeight` and `maxHeight` parameters set.

## Problem 2 - Vertical centreing is off if the page is scrolled

Next, I've noticed that as I scroll down the page, the `Dialog` is displayed further down the page also. My positional target is `window` (the default), so this should not be happening.

Does anybody know how to fix these problems? Thanks.

## JavaScript

```
$('#loading-dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    draggable: false,
    height: 94,
    maxHeight: 94,
    minHeight: 94,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    width: 350,
    open: function(event, ui){
        $(this).closest('.ui-dialog').css({ // Remove the borders and padding
            'background-image': 'none',
            'border':           'none',
            'padding':          '0'
        });
        $(this).closest('.ui-dialog').children('.ui-dialog-titlebar').css('display', 'none');
        $(this).closest('.ui-dialog').children('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').css('display', 'none'); 
    }
});

/** Show the AJAX loader */
$('#loading-dialog').dialog('open');

/** Hide the AJAX loader */
$('#loading-dialog').dialog('close');
```

## HTML

```
<div id="loading-dialog">
    <div id="loading-dialog-inside">
        <span id="custom-admin-preview-spinner">&nbsp;</span>
        <h2>Generating preview...</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
#loading-dialog{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
}

#loading-dialog-inside{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 13px auto;
}
#loading-dialog-inside h2{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#custom-admin-preview-spinner{
    background-image: url('../ajax-spinner.gif');
    display: inline-block;
    height: 48px;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 48px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Dialog height incorrect on first show

As noted in my question, the height of the `Dialog` was always incorrect on the first show. To fix this I implicitly declared the height that I required for the `Dialog` content container in the `open` function -

```
$(this).closest('.ui-dialog').children('.ui-dialog-content').css('height', '80px');
```

As the dialog will always be the same height, it's fine in this instance. However, it's no good for users who wish to have a variable-height `Dialog`. Therefore if anyone knows a more definitive answer, I'd appreciate you posting it.

## Vertical position off centre

The next part of my question focused on the `Dialog` becoming off-centre (vertically) when it was shown, if the webpage was scrolled vertically.

To fix this I made use of the `using` parameter of the `position` property. -

```
    using:      function(target, element){

        /** Set the 'left' and 'top' values correctly so that the dialog is displayed in the centre of the screen */
        target.left = Math.ceil(($(window.top).width() / 2) - (element.element.width / 2));
        target.top = Math.ceil(($(window.top).height() / 2) - (element.element.height / 2));

        /** Update the CSS of the target element */
        $(this).closest('.ui-dialog').css(target);

    }
```

Before discovering the answer I first logged the values of `target` and `element` (I.e. `console.log(target)`). This allowed me to see that `target.top` was being incorrectly calculated. What I mean by that is that if my target is `window`, top should always be `0`. However, `target.top` was instead being calculated as the relative percentage of the defined `height` that I vertically scrolled.

**For example**, if `height` is `200` and I scrolled 75% of the way down the page, `target.top` was being set to `150`. This in turn skewed the calculation of `element.element.top`, meaning it was pushed down the page by that amount.

## The full solution

Should you wish to use this solution, note that the `HTML` and `CSS` from the question remain as they were.

```
$('#loading-dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen:       false,
    closeOnEscape:  false,
    draggable:      false,
    height:         94,
    hide:           400,
    maxHeight:      94,
    minHeight:      94,
    modal:          true,
    position:       {
        my:         'center',
        at:         'center',
        of:         window,
        collision:  'none',
        using:      function(target, element){
            
            /** Set the 'left' and 'top' values correctly so that the dialog is displayed in the centre of the screen */
            target.left = Math.ceil(($(window.top).width() / 2) - (element.element.width / 2));
            target.top = Math.ceil(($(window.top).height() / 2) - (element.element.height / 2));
    
            /** Update the CSS of the target element */
            $(this).closest('.ui-dialog').css(target);
            
        }
    },
    resizable:      false,
    show:           400,
    width:          350,
    open:           function(event, ui){
        
        /** Style the dialog box */
        $(this).closest('.ui-dialog').css({ // Remove the borders and padding
            'background-image': 'none',
            'border':           'none',
            'padding':          '0',
            'position':         'fixed'
        });
        $(this).closest('.ui-dialog').children('.ui-dialog-content').css('height', '80px');
        $(this).closest('.ui-dialog').children('.ui-dialog-titlebar').css('display', 'none');
        $(this).closest('.ui-dialog').children('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').css('display', 'none');
        
        /** Style the overlay */
        $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('background-image', 'none');
                
    }
});
```

Comment: I should rephrase: why this bug in jquery ui is still there... :)

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense!